# entity framework not recognising data type / column format from SQLite

Tags: entity-framework, sqlite

Scene:

- SQLite3 database as external source
- A number of views exist in the db
- Entity Framework
- edmx file doesn't seem to recognise the data type of the columns in the view even when CAST

Example:

```
In the SQLite db I have:

CREATE TABLE [dr] 
([ID] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
[CoalNum] INT, 
[InputTime] DATE)

-------------   

CREATE VIEW "J13" AS 
SELECT 
dr.ID,
date(dr.InputTime) as InputTime,
CAST (count(*) AS INT) as CoalNum
FROM dr
WHERE dr.InputTime >= "2010-01-13"
GROUP BY dr.ID, date(dr.InputTime)
```

When I update the edmx model, VS2010 can recognise "dr.ID", but it does not recognise "InputTime" and "CoalNum". The error message  is "doesn't support datetype".

In the sqlite3 management studio, I checked this view ("J13") and I found "InputTime" and "CoalNum" datetype is null

```
cid      name          type        notnull      dflt_value      pk   
------- ------------ ---------- ----------- -------------- --- 
0        ID            INTEGER     0                            0    
1        InputTime                 0                            0    
2        CoalNum                   0                            0
```

So I cannot update the data model in Entity Framework. Hopefully someone can help or provide further information before I yell bug.
A man have the same question,but i don't know did he solution it.
https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?t=27214

Comment: What data types do each field of the `dr` table have?

Comment: in dr table: ID INTEGER, CoalNum INT,InputTime DATE

Comment: But according to the Sqlite documentation the `date` type does not exist :/

Comment: no exist? sqlite support "typelessness",  in my example ,also  "InputTime" and "CoalNum"  data types is null,but i can still use this view  ("J13") in sqlite , i dont' use in entity framework.i don't know how to solution it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite [uses dynamic typing](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html), and thus does not have data types in computed columns.

Entity Framework assumes that all columns do have known types; this is not fully compatible with SQLite's architecture.

You could try a workaround: create a database with a fake `J13` table with data types, update the model, and then replace the database file with the real database while Entity Framework isn't looking.